# The requested page "/http://.. could not be found. (puts slash in front of URL)

Tags: uri

All of a sudden I cannot login because it says
The requested page "/http://testsite.com/user/login" could not be found.
It puts a slash before the URL

I have no idea where that comes from.

Comment: What did you click on to get to that url?  Is your login link faulty?  Or do you get the form but the form doesn't work?

Comment: The problem was that any url suddenly returned this error message, no matter what link because I also tried typing urls directly in the address field of different browsers. The next mornging the problem was vanished by itself

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have changed the $base_url variable in settings.php file in sites/default folder.

Comment: No, the base url was not set in settings.php. For some reason the problem resolved itself when I woke up today. I have now put the domain as base url and see if the error message will stay away.

Comment: The problem appeared again, so the base url is not the cause.